# Count unique keys - mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection of searches. Each search has a criteria object, which can have any combination of criteria. So something like:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "criteria": {
        "state": ["NY", "IL"]
        ... 
    },
    ...
}
```

I'm building a mongo aggregation pipeline, and I'm wondering how to project only the keys so that I can count them.

So far the first step of my pipeline is:

```
db.userSearch.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "criteria":1 } },
    ...
])
```

This returns all of the criteria objects correctly, now I need to project the keys somehow. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:
desired output: `{"state":20, "balance":5, "geolocation":10, ...}`

Comment: You can use $unwind https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: The criteria object is not an array though, and neither are it's sub objects

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the post ?

Comment: MongoDB query language doesn't support this as MongoDB is schemaless. You need to use some client side code or mapreduce.

Comment: @ares After some research it looks like mapreduce is probably the way to go

Comment: Do you want to count the number of elements in states/balance/gelocation array for each document in collection?

Comment: Based on your ouptut it looks you just need count and keys. Something like this should work.`db.userSearch.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "criteria":1, "state" : {$size: "$criteria.state"} } },  ...
])`. You'll need to group if you want over the entire collection.

Comment: There are an arbitrary number of keys, new criteria can be added later, which would break the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, I used mapReduce as follows.

```
map = function() {
    Object.keys(this.criteria).forEach(function(k) {
        emit(k, 1)
    })
}

reduce = function(k, vals) {
    return Array.sum(vals)
}

db.userSearch.mapReduce(map, reduce, 'out')
```